# What solutions with npm + wsl + docker and volume mounts?

Tags: docker, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to work on a web project relying on Docker and NPM (This is actually a LAMP server). I am running on WSL with the Docker daemon running on Windows.

Here are my constraints:

- To mount volumes with Docker I must locate my project on the Windows filesystem *e.g.* `/mnt/c/...`
- To use `npm` which use soft links, I must locate my project on the WSL filesystem *e.g.* `/srv/...`

Obviously I cannot meet these two requirements.

For instance if I do npm install from WSL on a folder located on the Windows filesystem I get plenty of errors such as:

```
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
```

Or, simply the modules don't work `webpack not found`

If I move my project on the WSL side, Docker is not able to mount my project on my target container...

What alternative can I use ?

Comment: Can you do routine development using Node on your host without Docker involved at all, and when you do need Docker, `COPY` the built application into your image?  That way you won't need volumes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using WSL, Docker for Windows expects you to supply your volume paths in a format that matches this: `/c/Users/username/dev/myapp`.

But WSL uses the `/mnt/c/Users/username/dev/myapp` format.

You have to configure WSL to mount at `/` instead of `/mnt`.

Create and modify the new WSL configuration file:

```
    sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf

    # Now make it look like this and save the file when you're done:

    [automount]
    root = /
    options = "metadata"
```

> We need to set root = / because this will make your drives mounted at
>   /c or /e instead of /mnt/c or /mnt/e.
>
> The options = "metadata" line is not necessary but it will fix folder
>   and file permissions on WSL mounts so everything isn’t 777 all the
>   time within the WSL mounts. I highly recommend you do this!
>
> Once you make those changes, sign out and sign back in to Windows to
>   ensure the changes take effect

source:
https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly